# Calculus book recommendation.

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation, infinitesimals

Currently I can't buy any Calculus book. But I have a list of free books, which legal to download. But I don't know which one is best. I want to learn inner mechanics of Calculus deeply as a pure mathematics student and I think my background is enough for it. Here is the my list. Which one would you prefer?

1. GILBERT STRANG, EDWIN "JED" HERMAN,
   Calculus. (From openstax)
2. Gilbert Strang - Calculus
3. Jerrold Marsden , Alan Weinstein - Calculus1
4. Peter D. Lax,Maria Shea Terrell
   -Calculus With Applications
5. Matthew Boelkins,David Austin Steven Schlicker Active Calculus
6. Michael Corral - Elementary Calculus
7. Lyryx Learning based on the original text by D. Guichard

- Calculus – Early Transcendentals
  an open text

8. H. Jerome Keisler -Elementry Calculus an infinitesmall approach
9. David Guichard., expansion of notes written by Neal Koblitz - Single and Multivariable Calculus
   Early Transcendentals
10. J.H. Heinbockel - Introduction to Calculus
11. Dan Sloughter - Yet Another Calculus Text A Short Introduction with Infinitesimals
12. SILVANUS P. THOMPSON CALCULUS MADE EASY

Comment: What is your background, what are you required to know and how deep do you want to go? These are all questions you should include in the body of your post.

Comment: @Spring, I have edited the question.

Comment: I would cross Strang and Marsden off the list.  The writing style appeals to professors, but not to students.  It's a problem in academia; someone who already knows the material will find a textbook "wonderful" because they easily understand everything they read.  Not many profs have the skill to read a text through a student's eyes.  Those two authors are popular, but for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Ok, any suggestion ?

Comment: You may also try Khinchin's *A Course of Mathematical Analysis*. Despite its name, it is mostly a calculus book because it doesn't touch upon point-set topology. However, it is deep in content. The book is out of print but a scanned version can be downloaded from archive.org. I haven't really read this book but I have once read the section on expansion of functions into power series and thought “oh, I wish this was the assigned textbook when I was an undergraduate student”.

Comment: Another book that I have heard good words about is Kitchen's *Calculus*, which has a new (2020) Dover reprint. In an amazon review, some recalled that in Kitchen's teaching evaluation report, it was written that “A large minority of professor Kitchen's students believe that he is God”. I am interested to know why but I haven't the chance to read this book yet.

Comment: There are two different approaches to calculus at this level. One is by the epsilon-delta definition of the limit that has been the mainstay of mathematics from the early 1800s to the 1960s, and is still the majority favorite today. The other makes the pre 1800s concept of infinitesimals more rigorous and was introduced in the 1960s. It is conceptually easier in some ways than the epsilon-delta approach, but relies at one point on an axiom that says "it just works in general, don't ask how" that you must accept (I'll get boos for that, but it is how I see it). You have both in your list. cont.

Comment: (continuing) I suggest you decide which approach you want to study, and make sure you are fully comfortable with that version before you even look at the other. Likely the majority of the calc-books are epsilon-delta. Those with "infinitesimals" are likely the newer (but also older) non-standard-analysis approach. Possibly the "Transcendentals" as well, but I could easily be wrong. Check where they define limits and then the derivative to determine which is which. For the epsilon-delta approach, if you find one that talks about Henstock-Kurzweil instead of Riemann integration, choose it.

Comment: For me, Marsden and Weinstein's book is nice. But for main textbook, I would go with James Stewart or Louis Leithold or Purcell and Varberg's book, although these books are not free.